# Replacing double quotes with single quotes in windows notepad++

Tags: windows-8.1, notepad++

I have a file which has contents similar to this...

10004 "ALCAZAR     " 115.0000 :  1 1.00000 1.042060   2.70188  10

Now I want to replace all the double quotes in that file with that of a single quotes.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to replace all the double quotes in that file with that of a single quotes.

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `"`
- Set "Replace with" to `'`
- Enable "Normal"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
10004 "ALCAZAR " 115.0000 : 1 1.00000 1.042060 2.70188 10
```

**After**:

```
10004 'ALCAZAR ' 115.0000 : 1 1.00000 1.042060 2.70188 10
```

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)